# How do you calculate total Thrust and Specific Impulse for a rocket stage?

Tags: engines, thrust, specific-impulse

Given the stage has the following configuration:

```
Thrust
  741.4 kN (Main)
   47.1 kN (Vernier)
Specific impulse
  297.999 s (Main)
  288.999 s (Vernier)
```

How would I calculate the total thrust and specific impulse for the stage?

Comment: Search for a recent question called "how does the rocket equation work when you have boosters", the answer gives the equation you need. Can't post link, on primitive device.

Comment: @OrganicMarble https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25164/how-does-the-rocket-equation-work-when-you-use-boosters So that gives me the total SI. But how do I get total Thrust?

Comment: You add the two thrust numbers together.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I like the term "primitive device". I makes me think you are using a [Timex Sinclair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timex_Sinclair_1000) or a [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) when in fact you are probably on something a hundred thousand times more powerful.

Comment: "I am endeavoring to construct a mnemonic memory circuit out of stone knives and bearskins" - Spock

Comment: @OrganicMarble Ha! I was thinking of precisely the same thing! Although I would never have been able to come up with more than the last four words. Fascinating.